# NodeJS + MongoDB - Want to add more nested values

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb

I have the following JSON structure:

```
 JSON =  { "change_number": "CRQ91320s23",
         "change_description": "Nexusg work",
         "date": "2/10/2020",
         "changeowner" : "Jeffre Hocking",
         "implementer" : "john Elazi",
         "PVT_testers": {
           "Epic": {
             "contact": "nathanbdas",
             "email": "James@gdasdamail.com" }}
```

I am using mongoDB + NodeJS to interface with it..

I want to add another entry beside "Epic" under "PVT_testers"..

This is my code, and when I run it, it replaces Epic with EPIC2 rather than adding to the same level.

Have cleaned the code to make it easier.

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  var dbo = db.db("radar");
  var myquery = {  "change_number" : req.params.id };
  var newvalues = { $set: {"PVT_testers"  : {"EPIC2" : {"das2": "asd", "das2": "asd", "results": { "pre_outcome":"sucess" }}}     }}
   dbo.collection("changes").updateOne(myquery, newvalues, function(err, res) {
      if (err) return res.json("Error:Database error" ); 
    console.log(res)
    db.close();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using $set operator, you are updating the whole object (sub-document in mongodb linguo). To add a new field, use the dot notation:

```
var newvalues = {
  $set: {
    "PVT_testers.EPIC2": {
      "das2": "asd", 
      "das2": "asd", 
      "results": { 
        "pre_outcome": "sucess" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helps a bit..

But the new addition is what looks like a list?

Comment: you mean like an array ?